# Authentication between two web applications

Tags: authentication, web-applications, oauth, saml

I have two web applications and I want to perform authentication of 2nd web app from 1st web app.
As of now, I am sending out the 1st web app's JsessionId in the hidden form parameter to the 2nd app. Using this 2nd web app performs authentication. I feel sending jesessionid in the hidden form parameter is not secure. How can I do this securely without OAuth or SAML?

Comment: "How can I do this securely without OAuth or SAML?" did you mean "with" OAuth or SAML?

Comment: I was looking for a way without any of the taken-based authentication mechanisms be it OAuth , SAML, or any other.

Comment: for sure you need some kind of temper proofing, like a signature. What about creating a simple signed JWT with a subject that specifies the user being authenticated and sending this along instead of `jsessionid`?

Comment: you can rely on third party SSO provider, such as Kerberos.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr How do i send this JWT token securely?? Because if this is exposed mean that of gaining auth access for 2nd application,